# Где развернуть Spring MVC приложение находясь в России?

Tags: spring, mvc, deploy

Я начинающий Java developer и для своего портфолио я написал Spring MVC приложение. Теперь я хочу что бы оно было доступно не только на localhost. Я потратил целую неделю что бы разобраться что к чему на Heroku и в конце концов выяснил что я не могу задеплоить своё приложение потому что даже бесплатный тариф подразумевает привязку карты.
Вопрос каким сервисом можно воспользоваться из России что бы не стать жертвой санкций?

Comment: бесплатно - хз... платно - Yandex Cloud, (у vk и mail.ru group тоже какое-то свое облако было) и любой российский хостинг с VPS/VDS, арендой или размещением сервера + некоторые хостинги предоставляют спец услуги с готовыми серверами приложений для хостинга JVM based приложений.

Comment: heroku.com вроде ещё шевелится